# Is a PERC310 Mini compatible with an R610?

Tags: raid, hardware, dell-poweredge, hardware-raid, dell-perc

I'm going to purchase an R610 soon which is sans RAID card. The [spec sheet](http://www.dell.com/downloads/global/products/pedge/en/server-poweredge-r610-specs-en.pdf) lists 2x PCIe x8 + 1 "storage x4" slot. However none of the X10 series cards are listed on the spec sheet.

I presume that's due to the HX10 (H310, H710, H810) coming out with the RX20 series servers, but I can't find anything online to advise if they're backwards compatible.